# anomaly/outliers detection in a multilabel dataset on the outcomes

Tags: outliers, multilabel, anomaly-detection

Assuming a multilabel dataset contains a few wrong data. **If so, is there a way to predict those wrong outcome given the fact there is a 'pattern' in the predictors?**

Let's use 'baby and silly' example:

Imagine a dataset where 30 respondent give their choice regarding the ice-cream preferences (vanilla, chocolate, coconut). All outcome combination are possible. We also collect the following features/predictors [MAN , AGE, IS_MANAGER,HAS_HOUSE, HAS_SEA_VIEW]

To make it simple imagine there is 3 patterns

- Those who like only vanilla ice cream are 'young', men and manager [see image 'grey 1' row 1 to 11]
- Those who like only chocolate ice cream are 'adult', woman and own a house [see image 'grey 2' row 12 to 21]
- Those who like vanilla and chocolate ice cream are 'old', men and are manager and have a view on the sea [see image 'grey 3' row 22 to 31]

As the image shows the aim would be to detect case 6 and case 17 [see yellow highlight on image] as un-correctly labelled.

[image]

Comment: "baby and silly" sounds like "toy".  Perfectly reasonable use.  I would use a random forest, because it is robust.  This means that a few "wrong" or "noisy" samples do not cause poor results.

Comment: Hello EngrStudent, thanks for the answer. Well I know that a few sample usually do not cause poor result. So I belive I can get good result when predicting new data. But in my case I really not aim to do that! In my case I onlyaim to find out that case number 6 and case number 17 are wrong!

Comment: So make a robust fit, predict, and look for big errors.

Comment: Could you tell me more about it? Any docs OR packages to use? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like **subspace outlier detection** to me.

try these: [Google Scholar "subspace outlier detection"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=subspace%20outlier%20detection)